# I want to respond images with Django

Tags: python, django

I want Django to display an image when accessed.
For example, I want to display only the image as a response, 
such as when accessing the image below.
And I want to do the URL as a normal URL without using .jpeg or .png.

Sample:

[image: sample]

But now, no matter what method you try, it doesn't work.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os
from django.core.files import File
import codecs


def image(request):
    file_name = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        '12.jpg'
    )
    try:
        with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
            a = f.read()
            return HttpResponse(a, content_type="image/jpeg")
    except IOError:
        red = Image.new('RGBA', (1, 1), (255, 0, 0, 0))
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
        red.save(response, "JPEG")
        return response




urlpatterns = [
    url('image', image)
]
```

With the above code, the following error occurs.

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Please post _the full traceback_, not just its last line

Comment: Usernames are the new tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [**`FileResponse`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects):

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def image(response):
    img = open('path/to/12.jpg', 'rb')
    response = FileResponse(img)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause was my own middleware.
There was no problem if I commented out.
Thanks for those who have comments and those who have answered.